# open online PDF file when a link is provided in browser in my application in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, browser

I am working on an application in which i need to download a PDF file, from a url.
After download I have to open that PDF file for user but as i dnt have any default app for PDF, i working to open that PDF file in browser as google doc with its url.

```
"http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdfURL
```

where pdfURL is the url of PDF on server.

Problem: When ever I open the browser with the help of below code:

```
BrowserSession myBrowser = Browser.getDefaultSession();
myBrowser.displayPage("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

But the result is as shown in the image:
[image]

The data loading task stops at 28k always and same this picture appears in every case for every url.
Please help me in doing this task. Whats the actual problem with my code?

Comment: is this on the simulator, or the device?  which device/simulator?  which OS version?  if it's the simulator, are you running the MDS?  can you open up the normal BlackBerry browser from outside your app (don't run your app at all), and get web pages to load?

Comment: This is my simulator and yes, MDS is checked, its working as I already used the sample blackberry browser field in which I opened google. I think I need to try this in device......but as browser field code is working in simulator then it must also work.